# Assign reducer to nested state property?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

With the react/redux setup below:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './components/app';
import configureStore from './store';

let initialState = {
  foods: {
    apple: {
      selected: false,
      flavors: {
        sweet: true,
        salty: false
      }
    },
    potatoChips: {
      selected: false,
      flavors: {
        sweet: false,
        salty: true
      }
    }
  },
  drinks: {
    < some other object >
  }
}

let store = configureStore(initialState);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

store.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './root-reducer';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

let finalCreateStore = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk, logger())
)(createStore)

let defInitialState = < same object as initialState above >

export default function configureStore(initialState = defInitialState){
  return finalCreateStore(rootReducer, initialState)
}
```

root-reducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import appleReducer from './apple-reducer';
import potatoChipsReducer from './potato-chips-reducer';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  foods.apple: appleReducer,
  foods['potatoChips']: potatoChipsReducer
  // HOW DO I DO THE ABOVE ASSIGNMENT?
})

export default rootReducer
```

Can I assign a reducer to `state.foods.apple` like how I'm trying to do in `root-reducer.js` above? Or should I be going about this in a different way?

extratextsothisquestionisntallcodeandcanbesubmitted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can nest `combineReducers`.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/2rhs2m9y/

```js
const foodsReducer = combineReducers({
  apple: appleReducer,
  potatoChips: potatoChipsReducer,
})

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  foods: foodsReducer,
})
```

So your `appleReducer` will receive only the `foods.apple` tree as its state, and so forth.

You could alternatively do (which is essentially what `combineReducers` is doing for you):

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  foods: (state, action) => ({
    apple: appleReducer(state.apple, action),
    potatoChips: potatoChipsReducer(state.potatoChips, action),
  }),
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for